# Чёрный и белый кот были спасены-таки

Tags: согласование

Можете сказать, как в таких случаях, которые часто, между прочим, происходят, писать надо бы то по-грамматическому и говорить так же? Я имею в виду, как быть нам, если мы только одно существительное используем, чтобы показать, что там-то на самом деле несколько, и мы это показывает посредством использования прилагательных нескольких, когда они к одному таки существительному ссылаются-таки.

Например (как правильно?):

1.1. Чёрный и белый кот был спасён.

1.2. Чёрный и белый кот были спасены.

1.3. Чёрный и белый коты были спасены.

1.4. Чёрные и белые коты были спасены.

Я предполагаю, что, если мы используем 1.4., мы имеем-таки в виду, что там было несколько и чёрный, и белых котов таки, что не является тем, что мною-то подразумевается. Если 1.2. нами таки используется, то происходит несогласование: *кот + были.* В соответствии с тем, что я чаще всего вижу, то, если грамотно-таки, то надо, наверное, 1.3. выбирать-таки, но в разговорной речи 1.1. тоже, по-моему, нормально. Что думаете, совы-филины?

Comment: Не вешайте частицу на частицу! Это неправильно.

Comment: В первом варианте получается, что кот один (поскольку "был") — чёрно-белый.

Comment: @Pumpkin Совы-филины думают, что с краткими причастиями частица *таки* пишется раздельно: **были спасены таки**. (http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_122)

Comment: А вообще-то в данном случае это краткое прилагательное выступает как часть сказуемого, из-за чего, сэр, дефис нужен. Об этом, однако, даже сам Розенталь не написал, но, к счастью, Лопатин-мистер нам все тонкости прописал. Сами посмотрите: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=75#pp75.

Comment: Или Вы думаете, что Лопатин - лжец-таки? (Это тоже часть сказуемого - дефис нужен.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если про цвет одного кота, то пишут чёрно-белый.

1.4 - это если много разных, но монохромных котов.

1.3:
Если два кота разного цвета, то "спасены коты: чёрный и белый" или "чёрный и белый - коты были спасены", "чёрный и белый коты были спасены" - допустимо*, но есть некоторая неловкость в прочтении(фраза, сказанная спасателем котов, его доклад). Либо "были спасены чёрный и белый коты" - сказуемое должно идти раньше чем обстоятельства, если речь идет о какой-то информации, новости, то есть это стиль новостей или научный, а если вы сначала пишите про дополнение, а не про основное действие, то это что-то литературное, тут уже зависит от того, про что вы пишите, то есть от предыдущего контекста, история про котов получится, а не про того, кто их спас(*этот случай).

1.1 и 1.2 - не верно. Кроме того, признак априори < чем существительное к которому он относится, если "признак" больше, чем определяемое слово, тогда речь идет не о прилагательных, а о кличках: Чёрный и Белый коты были спасены.